# My python pyw file isn't opening though there's no error

Tags: python

I invented a secret code for converting messages. I thought of making a python program which will do the tough steps(basically encoding the messages and decoding them) and saved the code into a .pyw file. But it seems its not opening, I've renamed the file to .py and when I run it the console window opens, no error, and then closes. If I run the program via IDLE the program works fine and there's no error, is this some sort of bug and I should re install python or something else

```
from tkinter import Text,Button,Tk,Label,Scrollbar,Frame

alphabets={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,'e':5,'f':6,'g':7,'h':8,'i':9,'j':10,'k':11,'l':12,'m':13,'n':14,'o':15,'p':16,'q':17,'r':18,'s':19,'t':20,'u':21,'v':22,'w':23,'x':24,'y':25,'z':26,' ':' '}
inv={k:v for v,k in alphabets.items()}

#scripting the program

def insert(msg,char,index):
    return msg[:index]+char+msg[index:]

def encode():
    msg=_input.get('1.0','end').strip().lower()
    if msg=='':
        return ''
    if msg[-1]=='\n':
        msg=msg[:-1]
    nonconvertable={}
    for x in msg:
        if x not in alphabets:
            print(x)
            nonconvertable.update({x:msg.index(x)})
            msg=msg.replace(x,'')
    char=[]
    msg=msg.split()
    for item in msg:
        for x in item:
            number=len(item)
            num=alphabets[x]-number
            if num<=0:
                num+=26
            char.append(num)
        char.append(' ')
    msg=''
    for x in char:
        msg+=inv[x]
    for x in nonconvertable:
        msg=insert(msg,x,nonconvertable[x])
    return msg[:-1]

def decode():
    msg=_input.get('1.0','end').strip()
    if msg=='':
        return 
    nonconvertable={}
    for x in msg:
        if x not in alphabets:
            nonconvertable.update({x:msg.index(x)})
            msg=msg.replace(x,'')
    char=[]
    msg=msg.lower().split()
    for item in msg:
        for x in item:
            number=len(item)
            num=alphabets[x]+number
            if num>26:
                num-=26
            char.append(num)
        char.append(' ')
    msg=''
    for x in char:
        msg+=inv[x]
    for x in nonconvertable:
        msg=insert(msg,x,nonconvertable[x])
    return msg[:-1]

#script for interaction of the user(through the GUI) with the script

def encodeGUI():
    msg=encode()
    output.delete('1.0','end')
    output.insert('1.0',msg)

def decodeGUI():
    msg=decode()
    output.delete('1.0','end')
    output.insert('1.0',msg)

#building the GUI

root=Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.title('converter')
root.configure(background='#747f91')

note=Label(root,text="NOTE: Don't use a dot(.) in your message",bg='#747f91')
note.grid(row=1,column=5)

inputlabel=Label(root,text='Input',bg='#747f91')
outputlabel=Label(root,text='Output',bg='#747f91')
inputlabel.grid(row=1,column=1)
outputlabel.grid(row=3,column=1)

_input=Text(root,height=15,borderwidth=1)
_input.grid(row=2,column=1)
frame1=Frame(root,width=_input.winfo_width(),height=_input.winfo_height())
frame2=Frame(root,width=_input.winfo_width(),height=_input.winfo_height())
inputscrollbar=Scrollbar(frame1,command=_input.yview)
frame1.grid(row=2,column=3)
frame2.grid(row=4,column=3)
inputscrollbar.pack(fill='y')
output=Text(root,height=15,borderwidth=1)
output.grid(row=4,column=1)
outputscrollbar=Scrollbar(frame2,command=output.yview)
outputscrollbar.pack(fill='y')

encodebutton=Button(root,text='encode',command=encodeGUI,bg='#6179c9')
decodebutton=Button(root,text='decode',command=decodeGUI,bg='#6179c9')
encodebutton.grid(row=4,column=4)
decodebutton.grid(row=4,column=6)
```

Comment: I think the mainloop is missing. If I see it right, that's why it works in IDLE because in IDLE you do not "leave" the process, whereas from the command line your program wors but immidiately terminates. Haven't tried it yet, I confess, but maybe it gives you a hint.

Comment: thx, now the file is opening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you forgot to add:

```
root.mainloop()
```

at the end of the file.
But if the pyw file still won't run, these steps may help you:

1. Create a .pyw file
2. Right-click on it and select properties
3. In "Opens with:" press change
4. Navigate to your python directory and choose "pythonw.exe"

Comment: It worked! and btw i just had one doubt, wht does `root.mainloop()` do exactly?

Comment: @Dev `root.mainloop()` is the function that starts the GUI of root. Without it, it won't start, but the file will run, there isn't an error or something. Only in the IDLE it's working without the need of `mainloop()` function.